# How to change entity class in form type?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have tree almost identical entity classes: A, B, C (they all extends one superclass via Doctrine class table inheritance).

And i have a form that allows to choose proper entity class via ChoiceType. In fact i need possibility to change entity class via form on entity creation (when its not persisted)

I cant figure out how to create controller action that will hande:

- creation of new A/B/C entity
- changing the entity class (when i change class field - form will submit)
- persisting the entity

**Update**
I updated description and found solution (see lower)

Comment: Interesting question. I created a AbstractController (which extends AController, BController and CController) and a FormType (which extends AFormType, BFormType, etc.). Not sure that's the best practice.

Comment: Can't do or tell you much without appropriate code snippet.

Comment: How is the controller action being called? Three different routes?  If so then just add an internal parameter to the route definitions to indicate the entity.  But it sort of sounds like you should take a look at the many existing CRUD libraries and see how they do it.

Comment: @cerad, I asked this question in hope of somebody can point the project or approach that implements this behaviour. Have no time to dig thru tons of libraries(

Comment: Fair enough.  Just be aware that your question is so vague that it is doubtful that anyone can help you.  Hopefully I am wrong.

Comment: @cerad will update soon with sources and more explanations

Comment: @cerad, updated question a little and posted solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily use a DataTransformer to do that.

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html for how to doc it.

You can use the choice content to choose which class you need to create.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot about DataTransformers) Yes, i think it would be easier than my approach. Will check soon)

Answer (score 1):

Mulitple ways to go. Because I have little information here are some options:

#### On form level:

Add a Form-Type for all of your entities. Add an option to configure the `data_class` for the `ChoiceType`:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(['entity_class']);
}
```

Now use it when generating the form field:

```
$form->add(
    'entity',
    ChoiceType.class,
    ['data_class' => $options['entity_class']]
)
```

#### On database level:

Checkout how Doctrine handles [Single Map Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance). It gives you the ability to create a `BaseEntity` and extend entities `A`,`B` and `C` from it. Now you can simply add a `ChoiceType` (or `EntityType` for that matter) and select the `BaseEntity` as the entity.

The form will then show all entities within one field.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I already use class table inheritance. Now trying to work with base entity in controller. Have some issues getting child object instance (A B or C) instead of base extended object. Will reply about result tomorrow

Comment: i figured out solution, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39448230/2005817

Answer (score 0):

So, solution looks like that. Maybe someone will find it useful

**MySuperClassType.php**

```
protected function getAvailableEntityTypes()
{
    $availableTypes = array();

    // here i get all subclasses of MySuperClass to fill em in choice form

    foreach ($this->em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata() as $classMetadata) {
        if (is_subclass_of($classMetadata->getName(), MySuperClass::class)) {
            $availableTypes[$classMetadata->getName()] = EntityLabelBuilder::getEntityLabelTranslationKey(
                $classMetadata->getName()
            );
        }
    }

    return $availableTypes;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // here i add choice field with all available entity classes

    $builder
        ->add(
            'entityClass',
            ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'mapped' => false,
                'choices' => $this->getAvailableEntityTypes(),
            ]
        );

}
```

**MySuperClassController.php**

```
public function createAction()
{
    // initial entity creation
    $entity = new MySuperClass();

    // here i retrieve form data and recreate entity with class chosen in form
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if (in_array($request->getMethod(), array('POST', 'PUT'))) {
        $form = clone $this->get('my_app.my_super_class.form');
        $form->submit($request);
        $entityClass = $form['entityClass']->getData();

        $entity = new $entityClass();
    }

    // here i call form handler
    return $this->update($spend);
}
```